# HTTP POST array data in meteor

Tags: arrays, meteor, http-post

I need to post an array of data with the index number of the line. (If I send without the index in brackets, only the last item is being picked up by the server)
Problem is that js doesn't allow me to use brackets in the key name...

I tried to build a string with all the array data as `key[0] : 'value'` and than passed it in as one of the param, but that didn't work either.

```
  Meteor.methods({
  submit_order:  function(){
      var test = HTTP.call("POST", "https://example.com/api/",
      {
        headers: 
            { 
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            }
         , 
        data : {ApiLogin:'login',
            ApiKey:'key',
            OrderNumber:'ReactTest1',
            Items[0][ProductQty] : '1',  <--- problem is here
            Items[1][ProductQty] : '2'
      },

      },
  function (error, result) {
   if (!error) {
      console.log(result);
  } else{
     console.log("http post error");
  };
  });
}
```

});

In PHP its written as follows:

```
'Items'             => array(
                            1 => array(

                                'ProductQty'            => 2,
                                ),
                            2 => array(

                                'ProductQty'            => 1,
                                 ),
                            3 => array(

                                'ProductQty'            => 1,

                                )
                            ),
```

Comment: Maybe you need to build it like this https://jsfiddle.net/4oth7476/

Comment: nope doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close, you just need to set up the array in the following way:

```
{
  ApiLogin:'login',
  ApiKey:'key',
  OrderNumber:'ReactTest1',
  Items:[{ProductQty : '1'},{ProductQty : '2'}]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it technically works, but the server doesn't convert it very well. it expects to get it in this format: Items[0][ProductQty] : '1'. I'm adding to my question how its being done in php